# Spanish conflicts with another language

Tags: babel

I'm trying to test a feature for all Latin alphabet languages. Spanish causes this error if included with certain languages:

> ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \quoting already defined.
>
> --- TeX said ---
>                  Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.314 ...quot\romannumeral\es@quotdepth\endcsname}
> ```
>
> --- HELP --- No help available

Why?

PS: where can I get the complete list of latin-alphabet languages supported by babel?

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/International_language_support  
\usepackage[
afrikaans,
basque,
catalan,
croatian,
czech,
danish,
dutch,
english,
esperanto,
estonian,
finnish,
french,
galician,
german,
hungarian,
icelandic,
indonesian,
irish,
italian,
kurmanji,
latin,
latvian,
lithuanian,
ngerman,
polish,
portuguese,
romanian,
slovak,
%^^A%slovenian,
%spanish, %ERROR: LaTeX Error: Command \quoting already defined.
swedish,
swissgerman,
turkish,
turkmen,
%^^A%ukenglish,
ukrainian,
%^^Ausenglishmax,
welsh,
english
]{babel}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is easy to find out which language clash: simply comment the languages until the error disappear.

Comment: Have a look at the docs. Besides the `ldf` files, search the `ini` files for the string `script.name = Latin` (although support is still partial in some languages); there are about 170 `ini` files with that string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conflicting language is Galician.

Load `spanish` before `galician`, if you need both. If `spanish` has to be the main language, do

```
\usepackage[main=spanish,galician]{babel}
```

Comment: @erwann, this should be probably reported to the [babel-galician](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-galician?lang=en) package maintainer...

Comment: Using exactly this syntax, I still get the same error. babel 2020/03/22 3.42

Comment: @Rmano the maintainer has not specified a way to reach him.

Comment: @Erwann ...bummer. So maybe to Javier at https://github.com/jbezos/babel-spanish/issues?

Comment: @Erwann Have you solved the issue/conflict?